# How to use ediff with (hg) changesets?

Tags: ediff, version-control, mercurial

I have not found a good way to use `ediff` with Mercurial changsets. What I want is basically the functionality of `vc-dir`, but for committed changesets. The input should be a changeset identifier, and I want an overview of the changed files, and an easy way to invoke ediff on each file.

I have experimented with using a wrapper around `ediff-directories` as argument to `hg extdiff` but I don't get the overview for the changed files to work.

I use mq, but I don't think that should be an issue, as applied patches as far as I can tell are treated as other changesets.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is exactly what you ask for, but...

1. `M-x monky-log`, find appropriate changeset, click Enter

   (monky is a magit clone, fairly nice, give it a try if you haven't tried it)
2. `M-x xhg-log`, move to appropriate changeset, and press =

   (xhg is another sensible mercurial mode for emacs)
3. `M-x ahg-diff` (will prompt for revisions and display diff in diff mode)

   (ahg is yet another mercurial module)

All those modules may have more functionality of a kind, I haven't really explored (while I heavily commit from emacs and frequently review recent logs, for deeper complicated history analysis I prefer hgview or TortoiseHg).

---

**Update (after reading comment)**

This will require some work to polish, but the effect need not be that far:

a) In this *fancier log* of monky, try tapping Tab, n, Tab, n, ... a few times. This should hide diffs and leave only file changes info. I suppose this is the summary buffer you want. So you only need to trick monky to open log in compacted view by default (advising sth. to set monky-hide-diffs variable to 't before this buffer is populated will likely help)

b) xhg has xhg-ediff-file-at-rev, unfortunately not bound to anything. So harder part of the exercise is to extract current file name and revision from monky-commit buffer and call xhg-ediff-file-at-rev with those data (my first instinct would be to advise monky-refresh-commit-buffer to set some variable to current commit, but maybe extracting info from actual buffer would be simpler).

Not a true solution, but ....

Comment: Pressing return on a change set in monky-log basically yields a fancier variant of log-view-diff-changeset (unless I've missed something). It looks nice, but it was the ediff functionality I was after. This still shows the text diffs, and from the descriptions I'm guessing the others do too?

Comment: FWIW If you've seen and like the ediff features in magit, you could look for / raise a feature request for monky to port the `magit-ediff.el` library? (I would think that working to such functionality into monky for everyone would be the most valuable approach.)

Answer (score 0):

install latest find-file-in-project

`M-x ffip-show-diff-by-description`, but the output is in `ffip-diff-mode` instead of ediff-mode.

You can also setup `ffip-diff-backends`.